# NetLogo - Checkers(Draughts)

Tags: netlogo

This year I need to finish my bachelor theses, and my task is to create a game known as checkers(or draughts). It wouldn't be a problem, but I have to write it in NetLogo using the Mutli-agent approach. So I cant use those well-known algorithms as Min-max or alfa-beta pruning. As I said, I have to use the Multi-agent approach, because in NetLogo every single piece is an agent, and they can communicate with each other. So as my teacher said me, I have to create a completely new algorithm. Could someone give me any advice or suggestion how to start, or describe it how it should work?

Comment: This question might be too open-ended for Stack Overflow, which is typically for specific questions about actual code. If your question here gets closed or goes unanswered, try the netlogo-users group on Yahoo.

Answer (score 4):

You can get ideas from [this model](http://bert.stuy.edu/common/IntroToCompSci/NetLogoDemos/Checkers-AlbertLee.html) and get started to develop your own:

CHECKERS by ALBERT LEE MCS1 PD. 5

This is the board game checkers. It follows the same rules as regular checkers, but without double-jumps, or triple-jumps, etc. The goal of the game is to jump every single of your opponent's pieces. Jumping pieces is done by jumping diagonally, over an opponent's piece. Only one color of the board is used for moving. Players take turns moving. On a regular move, when you don't want to jump an opponents piece, movement of one diagonal space is allowed. A red piece can only move in the direction toward the black pieces when the board is set up, and the black pieces do likewise. However, when either player's pieces get to the other end of the board, they become a king, known as "kinging," and either color king can move both forwards and backwards. The same one diagonal space rule applies, unless the king jumps, which it can jump also either forwards or backwards.

In my program, there are two steps to moving. First, you select the piece with your mouse. Then, you select the patch that you want to move the piece to. If you select a piece and select another piece instead of the patch, instead of moving the initially selected piece to that new piece, the new piece becomes selected, and the same rule of moving applies. To jump a piece, select the piece you want to jump with, and if the piece you want to jump is "jumpable," which means that the piece you want to jump with is one space diagonally with the piece you want to jump, and the next patch in that direction has no pieces. After selecting the piece you want to jump with, select that patch with no pieces. The "jumped" piece leaves the board.

[image]

Comment: Hi Marzy, thank you so much for your post and your model, I've already finished my checkers for two human players, but my goal and the biggest problem is to create a computer player, i.e. AI. As I said, I cant use MinMax or AlfaBeta prunning algorithms, that makes this task little bit impossible for me :/